# Finding constants for $\ddot y=\sin|x|+\delta(x)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following: $\ddot y=sin|x|+\delta(x)$

Now of course we need to split it into two different functions

$$y''(x^{+})=sinx + \delta(x)$$
$$y''(x^{-})=-sinx + \delta(x)$$

Now for $\ddot y(x^{-})$ can I say that the $\delta(x)$ there is zero since the argument is negative?

$$y'(x^{+}) = -cosx + H(x) + C_1$$
$$y'(x^{-}) = cosx + H(x) + C_2$$

and finally:

$$y(x^{+}) = -sinx + H(x)x + C_1x + C_2$$
$$y(x^{-}) = sinx + H(x)x + C_3x + C_4$$

Since delta appears in the second derivative, the first derivative isn't continuous, but our function y(x) is continuous at x=0.

We get that 
$$C_4 = C_2$$

Now I'm having difficulties understanding how to find $C_1$ and $C_3$. We need to find the discontinuity (the "jump") and compare it.

$$ \int^{\epsilon}_{-\epsilon}\ddot y dx = y'(\epsilon)-y'(-\epsilon)$$

Now as $\epsilon \to 0$ we get that the lefthand side is equal to 1.

Therefore:

$$y'(\epsilon)-y'(-\epsilon) = 1$$

$$y'(0^-) - y'(0^+) = +cos(0) - H(0^+) - C_1 + cos(0) + H(x^-)   + C_2 $$

And heaviside of a negative argument is 0 , and positive argument is 1, and so we get

$$ 1 = y'(0^-) - y'(0^+)= 1 - C_1 + C_2  $$

Therefore we get that $C_1 = C_2 = 0$

Are my steps here correct in finding the constants of this second-order DE?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problems for each term on the right side separately. For the restriction of $x$ to the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ the first term gives
\begin{align}
y_1''(x)&=\sin(|x|)\\
 y_1'(x)&=-sign(\sin x)(1-\cos x)=-sign(\sin x)\cos x +sign(x)\\
 y_1(x)&=-\sin(|x|)+|x|
\end{align}
as the sign of $\sin x$ and $x$ coincide on that interval, and $sign(x)=H(x)-H(-x)$. The integration constants were chosen to give a nice result.

The other term gives 
$$
y_2''(x)=δ(x)\implies y_2'(x)=\frac12 sign(x),\;y_2(x)=\frac12|x|
$$
In total and adding the homogeneous solution
$$
y(x)=Ax+B-\sin|x|+\frac32|x|.
$$